# Django : How can we manage groups and permissions if we use the Microsoft Azure Authentication

Tags: django, azure, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I am a newbee in Django and I would like to know how I can manage groups and permission for differents users if I used the Microsoft Authenticatication that is explained in the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python.

Can we manage that in Azure AD ? Or should we add them the users to the django authentication after the Microsoft authentication is done ?

Can anyone explain me because I do not get how I should create groups after the Microsoft authentication ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `django-allauth`, a popular package for handling auth. It seems to support Microsoft auth as one of its providers.

I haven't tried the Microsoft auth provider, but generally, `django-allauth` will give your user an option to login using the provider login page. After the user login on the provider page, it will give your web some relevant information about the user (read about OAuth for more details). `django-allauth` will handle the information and create the user for you.

Reference:

- [`django-allauth` installation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)
- [`django-allauth`'s Microsoft provider](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#microsoft-graph)